# express javascript static files not being served

Tags: node.js

I have the following line in app.Configure:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The directory structure is:
/public/scripts/
however, only 1 script is served while the rest are not. 
This is what I have in jade template:

```
 script(src='/scripts/login.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(src='/scripts/menu.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(src='/scripts/json.js', type='text/javascript')
```

login is being served, menu and json are both 404.

How do i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the files are there? No extraneous characters? Errors in the terminal?

Comment: fixed, caused by an ntfs permissions issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, caused by ntfs permissions issue